# Rotate object around z axis, depending on a point

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, 3d

I have an object like a HUD on the front of a tube in Three.js however this Hud needs to align its self always depending on a vector point. This vector point is the high side of this point so the object has to be facing aligned with that point all the time regardless of the direction and position of the tube. To illustrate a problem I am attaching an image.

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyCoI.jpg

In the image the green arrow represents the pipe, the red line represents the vector point to with the circle image has to rotate around the z-axis to be aligned.

I tried calculating the angle of the vector point and its center point to calculate how much I have to rotate in z the axis to align it to the point. which works in some scenarios where the object is not upside down for example. To place the object I am using the last point of the tube and using the previous as look at to keep it always perpendicular.

```
rotateobject() {
    //set the object perpendicular to the pipe
      this.hudObj.lookAt(this.previouspoint);
      let zerovector = new THREE.Euler();
      //reset the rotation
      this.hudObj.rotation.copy(zerovector);
      this.hudObj.lookAt(this.previousActualPoint);

      //Line to be able to see if the object is aligned

      var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff
      });
      var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
      geometry.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3( this.previouspoint.x , this.previouspoint.y, this.previouspoint.z),
        new THREE.Vector3( ((this.previouspoint.x) + this.previouspointdata.highSide.x), ((this.previouspoint.y) + this.previouspointdata.highSide.y), ((this.previouspoint.z) + this.previouspointdata.highSide.z) ),
      );   
      var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
      this.scene.add( line );
        /// calculate angle and rotate in z axis
      var angleRadians = Math.atan2(parseFloat(this.previouspointdata.highSide.y.toFixed(1)), parseFloat(this.previouspointdata.highSide.x.toFixed(1)));
      if (angleRadians > 0 && angleRadians < Math.PI / 2) {
        this.hudObj.rotateZ(-(Math.PI / 2 - angleRadians) );
      }//0-90
      else if (angleRadians < Math.PI && angleRadians > Math.PI / 2) {
        this.hudObj.rotateZ((angleRadians - Math.PI / 2) );
      }//90-180
      else if (angleRadians > -Math.PI && angleRadians < -Math.PI / 2) {
        this.hudObj.rotateZ((-Math.PI/2  + angleRadians) );
      }//-180-90
      else if (angleRadians < 0 && angleRadians > -Math.PI / 2) {
        this.hudObj.rotateZ(-(Math.PI / 2 - angleRadians));
      }//-0-90
      else if (angleRadians === 0) {

      } //0
      else if (angleRadians === Math.PI || angleRadians === -Math.PI) {
        this.hudObj.rotateZ(-(Math.PI / 2) );
      }//180
      else {
        if(Math.sign(angleRadians) === -1){
         this.hudObj.rotateZ( Math.PI );
        } 
       }

    }
```

I really appreciate the help I am very stuck in this. thank you all for your help

Comment: Is the red line well-defined (known or at least able to be computed), or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the red line is an array of vectors that i have so thery are well defined

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are cartesian coordinates of a point on a sphere. If so, you need to know:

Coordinates of center of the sphere - **Xc, Yc** and **Zc** - radius of the sphere - **r** - and two angles - **phi** and **omega**, then you can get coordinates of that point - **Xp, Yp** **and Zp** - like this:

```
Xp = Xc + (r * cos(omega) * sin(phi))
Yp = Yc + (r * cos(phi))
Zp = Zc + (r * sin(omega) * sin(phi))
```

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VByV0.jpg)

Then, if you'd need object on that point facing the center, you can use lookAt function from THREE.js

```
object.lookAt( Xc, Yc, Zc );
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt

Comment: Let me give it a try with your solution, thank you for the reply